# How do I add protected registration fields with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using devise for authentication on Rails 3.1. Users are to be registered by administrators on my site (it's a site internal to a school, unknown people should not register.) Each user is alloted a role (Eg, student, teacher, admin, resource_person) on registration, and this role is used for authorizing activities.

Now I don't want the user to be able to edit their role, hence it's not placed under `attr_accessible`. Because of this, I'll have to manually set the role from the parameters when registering a user. Is there any simple way to do this with devise, or must I create a custom controller that inherits from the devise registration controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you simply want to be able to manage users as an admin, I think the best way is to simply create a CRUD interface for your users model (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface).

If you want users to be able to manage some of their model (e.g. password changing), simply authorize them according to their role.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I didn't think of it that way. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Devise is just so good at what it does we sometimes forget it just uses simple models we can manage ourselves :D